# is there an error in this join query that resulted in a very long exection time

Tags: mysql, select, join

Background: `MyISAM`

Table `users`:

```
user_id | email | first_name | last_name | registration_date |
```

Table `school`:

```
user_id |school_id | email | organization |
```

The following query was resulting in 400 and 600 second execution times:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.email, users.first_name, users.last_name,
school.organization FROM users 
LEFT JOIN school ON users.user_id = school.user_id 
ORDER BY users.registration_date DESC LIMIT 200
```

However, if I instead use a select all, the query runs instantly:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN school ON users.user_id = school.user_id 
ORDER BY users.registration_date DESC LIMIT 200
```

I didn't originally name the fields in the tables, and the respective email fields contain different data. If I use the `SELECT * query`, the `SCHOOL` table `email` data is being returned; but I need the `USERS` table `email` data. However when I tried the first query just naming the specific fields, it continually timed out. Did I make a simple/silly mistake in it? Is there a better way to get this data? Thanks.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the queries listed.  No reserved words, syntax appears correct. I'm just as baffled.  Queries are identical from the "FROM Clause" to the end...

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT users.*, school.organization`? How does that perform?

Comment: Also, can you `show create table` on these so we can inspect indices?